# How to use the color palettes of Material-Design, and how to calculate&choose them?

Tags: android, colors, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, color-palette

I have some issues with the guidelines:

1. On one hand, they say ([**here**](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-ui-color-application)) that 500 is the chosen one for toolbars:

   > Toolbars and larger color blocks should use the 500 color of the
   >   primary color of your app.

   On the other hand, they show an example by scrolling on the same page ([**here**](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-themes)) , showing the color of the action bar is 300, in these 2 images:

   - http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7OU9YTFNJakVobVU/style_color_themes_light1.png
   - http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B6Okdz75tqQsZ2hMLXNYWld2d3c/style_color_themes_light2.png

   Yet we know that "colorPrimary" is used for the actionBar, as written [**here**](http://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html#ColorPalette).

   What's the correct one?
2. I don't get how the colors are calculated. Why is it between 50 and 900? All I've noticed is that the darker the color, the higher the value of it.

   Is there any formula to convert between the values ?
3. I can't find guidelines for many color types (meaning which color of the color palette to choose for each type). Only those of the actionBar ("colorPrimary" , should be 500 or 300) and the statusBar ( "colorPrimaryDark", should be 600) . What about the others? For example, those:

   - colorAccent (theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields)
   - windowBackground , which is probably 200 according to the images I've shown on #1.
   - colorControlNormal, colorControlHighlight, colorControlActivated
   - textColorPrimary, textColorSecondary, textColorTertiary
   - actionMenuTextColor, actionModeBackground

   Maybe there are others that I've missed.

Comment: According to me they just told that 500's are best viewed colors, and made a palette to ease the work but its upto you how you design the app. There is no hard and fast rule to choose colors from those only.

Comment: @AnkitBansal So they say they recommend one color, but they use another?

Comment: Checkout my answer here for calculating the palette colors http://stackoverflow.com/a/40964456/127923

Answer (score 1):

Take a look, taht at the right corner, there is a Hexadecimal number (something like  #FFFFFF), thats the real color showed.

If you want, take a look that page,http://www.materialpalette.com/ , where you can choose the color you need to your app. Put it in a res file called "colors.xml"

Afeter that, you have to modify the syle, using your colors

```
<resources>
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Yes it is. and just with 2 clicks, you got all the pallete

Comment: But how are they calculated, and what about the other attributes?